# How do you submit a job on multiple queues with Torque?

Tags: qsub, torque

Using `qsub` I can submit a job to multiple nodes on the same queue:

```
qsub -I -q normal -l nodes=2:ppn=16
```

However I have another queue named hyper, is it possible to submit a job across two different queues?

Something conceptually like this:

```
qsub -I -l queue=normal:nodes=2:ppn=16,queue=hyper:nodes=2:ppn=16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot associate multiple queues with a job. It sounds like you want to request properties/features, like this:

`qsub -I -l nodes=2:ppn=16+nodes=2:ppn=16:fastmem`

Comment: They're distinctly separate queues, I would normally launch a job in the hyper queue with `qsub -q hyper ...`, and likewise with the normal queue. So I think the simple answer you're giving is no, but just to be sure, you're not saying use properties/features to specify one queue or another right? (I haven't used properties/features before)

Comment: Pretty much, yes, that's what I mean, but I presumed that your queues are linked to certain hosts, and that's typically done via node properties, as defined in TORQUE_HOME/server_priv/nodes:

http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/6-0-1/help.htm#topics/torque/3-nodes/nodeProperties.htm

http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/6-0-1/help.htm#topics/torque/4-serverPolicies/mappingQueueToRes.htm

You can, of course, also get much more advanced and flexible resource mapping via a scheduler like Moab, which supports reservations, node sets,  task distribution, throttling, backfill, etc.